# Is there a way to reject/recall your own flags?

Tags: support, flagging

I just flagged an answer that, IMO, was not actually an answer since it only gave a short and obvious "out-of-universe" explanation for a question. I flagged it as "should be a comment", only to realize it *was* a comment, and the commenter turned it into an answer later on purpose.

Is there a way to go back and un-flag something, or do I just hope my flag gets ignored? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to retract a flag. If you feel strongly enough, you can ping a mod in chat.

MSE post on it: 
[Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/172958)

Answer (score 7):

Since [August 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/271002), you can retract flags on questions and answers, but not on comments. To retract a flag, click the flag link again and the button should become “Retract Flag”.

Today, the corresponding section of the [Help Center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) has been changed accordingly:

> If, while your flag is still waiting to be handled, you re-open the flag dialog, you'll be presented with the option to *retract* your pending flag:
>
> [image: retract flag option]
>
> You cannot raise the same type of flag twice on a post: for example, if you retract a "spam" flag, you won't be able to raise a spam flag or an abusive flag in the future.
>
> Retract flags only when you're sure there's no need for the post to be flagged, or you become convinced that a more serious type of flag is needed.